# WPF - Set propeties of child controls of custom style

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-style

I have a custom style for a SearchTextBox. I have multiple Bindings in this control.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:SearchTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:SearchTextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <TextBox.InputBindings>
                            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=SearchCommand}" Key="Enter" />
                            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=DeleteSearchCommand}" Key="Esc" />
                        </TextBox.InputBindings>
                    </TextBox>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource WatermarkButtonCancelStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding DeleteSearchCommand}" Margin="0,0,22,0"/>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource WatermarkButtonSearchStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I am using the TextBox in my view right here:

```
<controls:SearchTextBox Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,6" />
```

How can I set the bindings in my view, not in the definition of the style. So that I can use the control in multiple Views with different bindings?

Comment: you could set the `DataContext` with different objects and leave the style as it is. Or you could add properties to your SearchTextBox for each Binding you need.

Comment: can you give me a code example please?

Answer (score 0):

Style for the custom TextBox:

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SearchTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SearchTextBox}">
                    <DockPanel DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:SearchTextBox}}}">
                        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                Style="{StaticResource WatermarkButtonCancelStyle}"
                                Command="{Binding DeleteSearchCommand}"/>
                        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                Style="{StaticResource WatermarkButtonSearchStyle}"
                                Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Text}"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="InnerTextBox"
                                 Text="{Binding Path=Text}">
                            <TextBox.InputBindings>
                                <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding Text}"
                                            Key="Enter" />
                                <KeyBinding Command="{Binding DeleteSearchCommand}"
                                            Key="Escape" />
                            </TextBox.InputBindings>
                        </TextBox>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Code of the SearchTextBox.cs:

```
public class SearchTextBox : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SearchCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(SearchTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

    public SearchTextBox()
    {
        DeleteSearchCommand = new Command
        {
            ExecuteHandler = o => Clear()
        };
    }

    public ICommand SearchCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand) GetValue(SearchCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SearchCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public Command DeleteSearchCommand { get; private set; }
}
```

Because the Command for clearing the TextBox is always the same, the SearchTextBox contains the Command for clearing it.

Now it is possible to use the SearchTextBox in a View and just set the `SearchCommand` property.

```
<local:SearchTextBox Height="30" Width="200" SearchCommand="{Binding DoTheSearch}"/>
```

As you can see in the style for the SearchTextBox, the Text is set as the parameter for the SearchCommand, so you can use it, where the command is specified.